# Redirect From Partial View - PUBLISHED not working but DEVELOPING is OK

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript redirection in my logon controller that open my home page if login was successfull: return JavaScript("window.top.location ='" + returnUrl + "';")

My logon controller is called by a sumbit inside  Ajax.BeginForm as a partial view.

While developing (F5 on my vs2010) my solution work perfect, but my published version (the one I upload to server) is not redering a full new view, **instead it is  refreshing the div in my targetid.**

My Partial View Code

```
@model Web.Models.LogOnModel
<div id="LogBox2">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "LogBox2",  }))
{         
<fieldset>...'All textbox capturing data here

            <input type="submit" value="LogOn" />           
</fieldset>
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful")
}
 </div>
```

My Controller Code

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                      && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return JavaScript("location.href ='" + returnUrl + "';");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                // If an ajax request was made return only the validation errors 
                // instead of the whole page
                return PartialView("LogIn2"); 
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

I really dont understand why debugging (F5) works OK bur Published NOT. Do you?
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether I understand your scenario fully. I think your production is working as it should do; Consider the scenario: the form is being submitted through Ajax, and the 'returnUrl' is null/invalid then the div 'LogBox2' will be updated with the response of the action 'Home/Index' line `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`

If your intention is to redirect the user to the path '*returnUrl*'  or the '*home/index*' while log-in is successful, then one solution could be replacing the line

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

with

```
return JavaScript("location.href =" + HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Url.Action("Index", "Home"), true) + ";");
```

You can also consider using [jQuery Ajax with ASP.NET MVC](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=AjaxOptions#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=Jquery%20ajax%20with%20aps.net%20mvc&oq=Jquery%20ajax%20with%20aps.net%20mvc&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...1168890l1178601l0l1179148l30l26l0l4l4l0l335l4209l2j20j3j1l30l0.frgbld.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=9cdb98ddbd527140&biw=1538&bih=815).